# Controlling Acidity - Comandante C40 MK3 RedClix & Bodum Chambord French Press 3 Cup - 12 floz

Tags: brewing-process, french-press, acid, grind-size

### Did I not brew long enough? Should I go finer & less time? Or coarser & longer brew?

I've been getting acidic brews using french press method.  Between sips I have a tart after taste in my mouth.  Really triggers my acid reflux. Just a minute after sipping my throat starts getting irritated.

I use Merit Coffee - Strawberry Field. It's a rotating natural they provide seasonally. Guatemalan, Anaerobic Natural, and [Strawberry, White Chocolate, Pear] notes.

I know it's expected with a natural coffee especially anaerobic, but I like berry & chocolate notes and this coffee is perfect when I use my Moccamaster or V60. I thought the pear description instead of citrus description implied it was not as acidic, but this one is kicking my butt using a french press.

I've been brewing @ 60g/1L ratio with 22g ground at 70 RedClix (35 clicks) I brew with 266.66g of water and add 100g of milk afterward and add additional water to adjust taste. I use the Bodum Chamford 3 cup french press. I brew using this https://youtu.be/st571DYYTR8 recipe modified to {3:30 + (break crust again) + 3:30}

> **22g x (266g+100g) @ 70 RedClix (35 Clicks) Comandante for 7 min.**

### Did I not brew long enough? Should I go finer & less time? Or coarser & longer brew?